# How does one say, "take someone under your wing" in French?

Tags: anglais, expressions

A literal translation might be "prendre quelqu'un sous ton aile." But the English version is an idiomatic expression that probably doesn't translate directly into French. So what is the closest French equivalent?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is "Prendre quelqu’un sous son aile", see [here](http://www.les-expressions.com/resultats.php?toid=6), and is quite commonly used. Note that the version: "tu l'as pris sous ton aile" where emphasis is put on the agent offering protection is less common, but still correct and good sounding.

Comment: I'd mention it **is** also an idiomatic expression in French.